# scattered data interpolation

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, interpolation

I have a set of data for example:

```
X Y Z

1 3 7

2 5 8

1 4 9

3 6 10
```

I would like to interpolate `Z` for `X=2.5` and `Y=3.5` .  How do i do it? I cannot use `interp2` here because `X` and `Y` are not strictly monotonic (increasing or decreasing).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like [`griddata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html) is the function you are looking for:

```
z = griddata( [1 2 1 3], [3 5 4 6], [7 8 9 10], 2.5, 3.5, 'nearest' )
```

Comment: yes, this works. Thanks a lot. is it not possible to use linear interpolation for this?

Comment: because when I'm entering 

z = griddata( [1 2 1 3], [3 5 4 6], [7 8 9 10], 2.5, 3.5, 'linear' )

The answer i get is Nan

Comment: so maybe your data is not linear?

Answer (score 10):

The currently preferred way to perform scattered data interpolation is via the [`scatteredInterpolant`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatteredinterpolantclass.html) object class:

```
>> F = scatteredInterpolant([1 2 1 3].',[3 5 4 6].',[7 8 9 10].','linear') %'
F = 
  scatteredInterpolant with properties:

                 Points: [4x2 double]
                 Values: [4x1 double]
                 Method: 'linear'
    ExtrapolationMethod: 'linear'
>> Zi = F(2.5,3.5)
Zi =
    6.7910
```

Alternate syntax,

```
>> P = [1 3 7; 2 5 8; 1 4 9; 3 6 10];
>> F = scatteredInterpolant(P(:,1:2),P(:,3),'linear')
```

For the advantages of `scatteredInterpolant` over `griddata` see [this MathWorks page on Interpolating Scattered Data](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/interpolating-scattered-data.html#bt7o6f0). In addition to syntactic differences, two main advantages are extrapolation and natural-neighbor interpolation.  If you want to interpolate new data with the same interpolant, then you also have the performance advantage of reusing the triangulation computed when the interpolant object is created.