# matlab interp2 with coder

Tags: matlab, mex, matlab-coder

I am trying to generate a mex file from my code using matlab's coder. I'm using interp2. Only when running the mex file I get an error "Grid values must be strictly increasing."
It seems that the grid values are monotonically increasing. 
Does someone know how to solve the problem?
Thanks

Comment: "It seems that the grid values are monotonically increasing"? are you sure they really are?

Comment: Also, it says "strictly" increasing. Are you sure not two consecutive values are the same?

Comment: I don't know if coder supports this, but it should work for any data: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21277035/2778484