# 2D interpolation at random distributed grid-points

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have a set of data-points for the value of `z` depending on `x` and `y`. I am searching for some method in order to interpolate `zi` for the for `xi`, `yi`.

The problem is that `x` and `y` are not distributed in an orthogonal grid. Instead the grid-points `x` and `y` are distributed randomly.

Is there any MATLAB function for this available? (Ideally in standard MATLAB w/o specialized packages - e.g. statistic toolbox or others).

Comment: How is it off-topic to ask a question about the availability of a built-in function within MATLAB to do something in MATLAB? This sounds very relevant, and the answer is reasonable (and possibly not obvious to average MATLAB users) and a useful thread for others to search.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21275574/scattered-data-interpolation/21277035

Comment: Off-topic?!?!  What a joke!  This is a duplicate, not off-topic.

Comment: The question's mention of specialized packages is referring to the toolboxes that cost extra on top of core MATLAB.  This is not asking for a recommendation for a tool/software/etc., it's asking for a relevant function to solve the problem.  It has an answer, several actually.

Comment: Yes chappjc, i have the feeling that people who voted to close this question are not aware of Mathworks pricing policy. Anyhow and most important  i got a good answer. The closing of this question does not bother me.

Comment: @BerndGit I'm more bothered by the malfunction of the SO community that led to the decision.  Only 1 of the 5 who voted to close as off-topic have any real [tag:matlab] standing.  But also, it is beneficial to the broader MATLAB community ("the internet") to have this post linked to the other.  That cannot be done while it is erroneously closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are after [`griddata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html). Assuming `xi` and `yi` follow a `meshgrid`/`ndgrid` rules, then:

```
zi = griddata(x,y,z,xi,yi);
```

Should do the trick for you.

Comment: Seems to be the function i was searching. Thanks.

Comment: @BerndGit happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I just had a thought, you mentioned 'random'... if you don't mean interpolation, and you actually mean fitting, there's a nice tool available called `gridfit`, which estimates values permitting noise in the measurements:

```
[zgrid,xgrid,ygrid] = gridfit(x,y,z,xnodes,ynodes,varargin)
```

http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8998-surface-fitting-using-gridfit

Comment: Does the meshgrid() limitation also apply here?

Answer (score -1):

`interp2` does just that:

```
Zq = interp2(X,Y,Z,Xq,Yq)
```

where you put the points you want to query in Xq Yq.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am afraid this won't work since afaik for interp2 the value of X and Y have to follow a meshgrid() distribution.  In my question X and Y are not on an ortogonal matrix.